# Cannot add a new property in HDFS/config/advance/custome-core-site

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ambari

how to add a property in HDFS/config/advance/custome-core-site?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You add properties by scrolling to the bottom of that pane and adding one.

But you must login as an Ambari administrator